# Alphabet mapped to values: How to find actual words that add up to given value?

Tags: algorithm, list, cpu-word

I came across a G+ post where someone shared:

```
If
  A B C D E F G H I J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z

Equals
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

Then
  K + N + O + W + L + E + D + G + E = 96% 
  H + A + R + D + W + O + R + K     = 98%

But
  A + T + T + I + T + U + D + E     = 100%
```

So much for that and for the fun of it, ignoring the percent trick
and leaving the rest of the talk to the G+ comments.

But I ask myself: What would be the best approach (algorithm) to find all the
words out of a given word list (a fixed set of n words) that add up to 100?

Comment: Oh, I always liked going to school. But 17 years later... this is purely out of curiosity. @wildplasser

Comment: @wildplasser Will Google-Translate qualify for "doing homework"? :-) But I don't think it will result in good grades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065553/python-get-all-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-number). Your specific problem, however, suggests an easier approach. Since the number of words in a wordlist is limited and always smaller than the number of character permutation up to the length of the longest word, you are best off by proceeding like this:

Let's assume we have a `charToNum` function, which maps a character to the corresponding number:

```
for each word in wordlist
  sum := 0
  for each character in word
    sum := sum + charToNum(character)
    if (sum > 100)
      break // Correct result no longer possible
  if (sum == 100)
    Add the word to the result set
```

Comment: +1 for saving some time by not looping over the entire word if the initial chars values already sum to greater than 100. (Of course this doesn't increase efficiency in a big-O sense.)

Comment: Thanks @MatthewAdams and Chris. As this one goes with an example and the break statement I'll accept it and +1 Matthew's.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the straightforward approach would be good- it's O(*n*):

1. Create a hash table relating each letter to the point value
2. Loop through the list. For each word, sum the values of the numbers associated with the letters in the hash table. If the sum is 100, print the word or mark it as found in some way (add to a new list or something)...

(You could argue about the O(*n*) I suppose, if you say that "words" can be arbitrarily long; though this is not a concern if the word list is a subset of the words in some language. If you have *m* be the max number of letters in a word, then the algorithm is O(*nm*). Still, at some point you're going to have to "look at" each letter and each word, so I can't imagine there is a more time-efficient algorithm.)

Comment: As in Chris's answer, you can save some time some time "by not looping over the entire word if the initial chars values already sum to greater than 100. (Of course this doesn't increase efficiency in a big-O sense.)" (quoting my other comment)