# Caching generators in Python

Tags: python, caching, generator, memoization

Working on [generating partitions of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065553/get-all-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-number), in a dynamic programming approach,

I write this piece of code :

```
def cache(f):
    memory={}
    def g(*args):
        if args not in memory:
            memory[args]=f(*args)
        return memory[args]
    return g

#@cache   remove # for cached version 
def sum_to_n_list(n, size):
    if size>1 :
        l=[]
        for i in range(n//size,n):
                for tail in sum_to_n_list(n - i, size - 1):
                    if i>=tail[0] : l.append([i]+tail)
        return l
    else : return [[n]]
```

For example the partition of 6 in 3 integers has three solutions : 6 = 2+2+2 = 3+2+1 = 4+1+1 :

```
In [9]: sum_to_n_list(6,3)
Out[9]: [[2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 1], [4, 1, 1]]
```

As expected, the cached version is faster :

```
In [10]: %timeit a=sum_to_n_list(20,10)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop

In [11]: %timeit a=sum_to_n_list(20,10)  # cached version
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop
```

I want to have the same improvement with a generator :

```
def sum_to_n_gen(n, size):
    if size>1 :
        for i in range(n//size,n):
                for tail in sum_to_n_gen(n - i, size - 1):
                    if i>=tail[0] : yield [i]+tail
    else : yield [n]
```

It works, but I can't obtain a cached version of this fonction.
How to do that ?

```
In [12]: %timeit a=list(sum_to_n_gen(20,10))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.91 s per loop
```

### EDIT

Thanks @user2357112 and @thomas-k for their useful remarks and advices.

My aim is here to use  a generator for clarity, because it hide the useless list manipulation in the program; not as memory saver.

So I finally find this solution :

```
def gencache(f):
    memory={}
    def g(*args):
        if args not in memory:
                memory[args]=list(f(*args))
        return iter(memory[args])
    return g

@gencache
def sum_to_n_gen(n, size):
    if size>1 :
        for i in range(n//size,n):
                for tail in sum_to_n_gen(n - i, size - 1):
                    if i>=tail[0] : yield [i]+tail
    else : yield [n]
```

That improve speed with the same factor :

```
In [23]: %timeit  a=sum_to_n_gen(20,10) #cached version
100 loops, best of 3: 2.61 ms per loop
```

My questionning now is :

- This memoization works , because all little sub problems are solved only once, and a new iterator is rearmed at each call.  but the generator benefit ( compute each next term on demand) disappear also for the external call. Have somebody a idea to keep this feature ?
- Is clarifying code a recognized quality of generators ?

Thanks for all contribution.

Comment: Memoization fundamentally conflicts with the generator approach, as the design tradeoffs are opposite. Memoization is about storing results to trade space for speed, while the generator approach is about *not* storing results. You can't have it both ways. At best, you can make a hybrid that stores results as it yields them, but the memoization logic becomes a lot more complicated, and it only provides any benefit in use cases where you consume enough of the generator to benefit from the cache, but not enough that it would have been better to just make lists.

Comment: Because it seemed like an interesting task, [here is](https://gist.github.com/takluyver/8cc2138018be0e074bc4) some simple caching machinery that allows you to iterate over a generator multiple times, by lazily adding values to a list. But as @user2357112 suggested, it's probably not what you want to do. I'm showing it because it's interesting, not because you should use it.

Comment: Thanks  very much user2357112 and thomas-k. I edit my post  consequently, with new interrogations ...