How does @cache and yield from work in recursive function?
I am trying to apply functools.cache on a recursive iterator. Applying the decorator however completely changes (lowers) the result. What is going on under the hood?
The code:
from functools import cache

@cache
def Blinking(v, i, N):
    if i >= N:
        yield v
    elif v == 0:
        yield from Blinking(1, i+1, N)
    elif len(str(v)) % 2 == 0:
       s = str(v) 
       yield from Blinking(int(s[:len(s)//2]), i+1, N)
       yield from Blinking(int(s[len(s)//2:]), i+1, N)
    else:
       yield from Blinking(v*2024, i+1, N)
        
res = 0
for v in [0]:
    for _ in Blinking(v, 0, 25):
        res += 1

print(res)


When you naively cache a generator function you cache the generator objects. You can only iterate over those once, then they're empty. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800326/caching-generators-in-python#comment57344491_34800326

It's pretty simple.
A generator function like the one above returns a generator, which is cached by the functools.cache.
i.e The same cached generator is returned every time you call the function.
>>> from functools import cache
>>> @cache
... def b():
...   yield 0
...   yield 1
...   yield 2
...   yield 3
... 
>>> 
>>> g = b()
>>> g
<generator object b at 0x73529c243ca0>
>>> c = b()  # Returns cached generator g
>>> g is c
True
>>> next(c)
0
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(g)  # g and c are the same objects
2



It looks like you're solving last night's (Dec 10) Advent of Code, and as you can see, returning an iterator from a @cache'd function is almost always the wrong thing. When using a cache, you almost always want to return a list or tuple.  If necessary, create a helper function that returns a list of the results of the generator function, and put a @cache on the helper function.
For this problem, there is a much easier solution.  All you care about is the values of the stones and how many there are of each of them.  Their order doesn't really matter.  A perfect use for collections.Counter.

It is true, this was one of my attempts that, as you might guess, failed terribly :D I was just curious about the behavior I did not understand.
