# Python: I have a string and a list of lists of varying lengths and I want to return the letters in groups as they correspond to the list

Tags: python, string, list

Imagine that I have a string that is 5 letters long, say 'ABCDE'.  I also have a list of lists of the different way to split the list i.e. [[5], [4, 1], [3, 2], ... [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]].  How could return all the different ways to split the list, like below.  The problem I am having is setting up a loop with uneven numbers of indices.

```
INPUT
'ABCDE', list_of_configurations

OUTPUT
['ABCDE']
['A', 'BCDE']
['AB', 'CDE']
...
...
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Final note, I want it be dynamic in that it can apply to a string of 5 characters or a string of 9 characters.  I was trying to figure this out but I think it is beyond my current skill level.

Comment: The question is overly broad.  "I don't know how to do X.  Please teach me." is not a question for StackOverflow.  Instead, make your best attempt at solving the problem, post your results and ask how to fix the particular problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply that configuration list of lists containing possible "slices" of a string, here is a way to do it - basically, we take a slice and pass the rest of the string to the next step:

```
s = 'ABCDE'
c = [[5], [4, 1], [3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

for item in c:
    result = []
    s_copy = s
    for index in item:
        result.append(s_copy[:index])
        s_copy = s_copy[index:]
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
['ABCDE']
['ABCD', 'E']
['ABC', 'DE']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: Thanks.  Once it is explained it often seems so simple!

Answer (score 3):

That is a classic brute force problem. You have to generate all options of where you can split the string. You can either split it between each two letters or not.

For string of length n there are n - 1 places you can possibly split it

```
a b c d e
 ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Thus, each binary (with only 0s (if you do not want to split string at that location) and 1s (if you want to split string at that location)) array of length `n - 1` corresponds to one possible split option. I.e.

```
[1, 0, 0, 0] <=> ['a', 'bcde']
[1, 0, 1, 0] <=> ['a', 'bc', 'de']
```

From each array you can generate the splitting. Thus, the problem is equivalent to looping through all the possible binary arrays.

You could do it using brute force recursion, but that is much easier to do just looping through the numbers from 0 to `2 ^ (n - 1)` and generating array based on binary representation of this number.

With all this said, that is the code that solves your problem.

```
def gen_all_splits(s):
    result = []
    for i in range(2 ** (len(s) - 1)):
        split = bin(i).replace('0b', '')
        split = '0' * (len(s) - len(split)) + split
        current_string_split = ['']
        for j in range(len(split)):
            if split[j] == '0':
                current_string_split[-1] += s[j]
            else:
                current_string_split.append(s[j])
        result.append(current_string_split)
    return result

print(gen_all_splits('abcdef'))
```

---

P.S. Thanks to comment, I just realized that I answered to broader problem that yours are. I will keep the answer, but you can use the piece relevant to generating the string by split configuration:

```
        current_string_split = ['']
        for j in range(len(split)):
            if split[j] == '0':
                current_string_split[-1] += s[j]
            else:
                current_string_split.append(s[j])
```

Comment: I think *the splits themselves are given* in the OP's case and it might not be needed to generate all splits in this particular case. Just get the slices dictated by the configuration list of lists. Great answer in any case.

Comment: Yeah.  Great answer.  I used the code linked below to get all the possible iterations but the way you did it is also really interesting and is extremely helpful if I ever decide to program outside of python.
jbochi answer at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065553/get-all-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-number

Comment: Although, it doesn't quite work.  I am trying to figure out why.  But to keep it simple if you enter the string 'ABC' you return [['AB'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'BC'], ['A', 'B', 'C']].  There is no ['ABC'] or ['AB', 'C'].

Comment: @DonQuixote Slight error in math that apears for short string. I fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but Python allows us to write this in much more compact fashion:

```
def my_split(string, config):
    return [string[sum(config[:i]):sum(config[:i+1])] for i in range(len(config))]
```

To get the result for all configurations, you simply need to loop over the given configurations and call the my_split function.