# Find all unique sets of k non-negative integers summing to n

Tags: algorithm

The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065553/get-all-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-number/2074693#2074693) question provides an implementation of an algorithm that given two numbers k and n can generate all combinations (excluding permutations) of k positive integers which sum to n.

I'm looking for a very similar algorithm which essentially calculates the same thing except that the requirement that k > 0 is dropped, i.e. for k = 3, n = 4, the output should be
[0, 0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 1, 3], ... (in any order).

I have tried modifying the code snippet I linked but I have so far not had any success whatsoever. How can I efficiently implement this? (pseudo-code would be sufficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def partitions(Sum, K, lst, Minn = 0):
    '''Enumerates integer partitions of Sum'''
    if K == 0:
        if Sum == 0:
            print(lst)
        return
    for i in range(Minn, min(Sum + 1, Sum + 1)):
        partitions(Sum - i, K - 1, lst + [i], i)

partitions(6, 3, [])

[0, 0, 6]
[0, 1, 5]
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 2]
```

This code is quite close to linked answer idea, just low limit is 0 and correspondingly stop value `n - size + 1` should be changed

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code provided on the other thread provided as is.

Then you want to get all of the sets for set size 1 to k, and if your current set size is less than k then pad with 0's i.e

```
fun nonZeroSums (k, n)
    for i in 1 to k
        [pad with i - k 0's] concat sum_to_n(i, n)
```