# How to solve this problem recursively in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

Let's say I have a set of variables ${x{1},...,x{n}}$ and a randomly given, but fixed number $s$. How to find the minimum number of variables required to sum up to that fixed number? We can presume, that the variables always sum up to the given number. So far I have achieved this:

```
def poss(x,s):
    if s<=0:
        if s==0:
            return 1
        if s<0:
            return -1
    else:
        for i in x:
            if poss(x,s-i)==1:
                print("right")
            if poss(x,s-i)==-1:
                print("wrong")
            else:
                pass
```

I know at some point I need to possibly create an array that keeps track of how many addings each branch has made and delete those that don't work, then take minimum of that, but I'm not sure where or how.

an example of output I calculated by hand:

```
print(poss([2,3],10)) --> output is 4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all numbers that add up to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065553/get-all-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-number)

Comment: I didn't know about the command 'yield' but is there any alternative to it?

Comment: Instead of `yield`, you can append the values to a list then return the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that when you use recursion inside for loops, all variables stored inside each recursion will be lost when exiting the recursion. To solve this we can capture the count of recursions (ie. the number of x elements used to reduce s) in a global variable, lets call memory.

Next we need to do three things:

1. The only instance in which memory should be changed is if s==0.
2. Memory count should only be changed when s==0 from the minimum number of subtractions. (*we can sort x from largest to smallest so that we start cutting s with the bigger values first. Example: x=[1,1,4], s=8 should output 2 since (s-4-4 = 0), not 8 (s-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 = 0) where every subtraction is a new recursion*)
3. We also need to make sure memory is only ever changed once (otherwise other combinations of elements in x will update it). To do this we can check the the value of memory prior to each following recursion and abort if memory has already been found.

The final code:

```
memory = 0
def poss2(x, s, count=0):
    
    big_to_small = sorted(x, reverse=True)
    global memory     # Call on global variable
    
    if s==0:     # Capture count in global variable. Recursion inside of for loops will lose all previous data.
        memory=count
        
    elif s<0:
        return count-1     # Go back, S too small
    
    else:
        for i in big_to_small: 
            if memory==0:     # If memory is till zero, s==0 was not yet achieved. Keep recursing with new s and count
                poss2(big_to_small, s-i, count+1)
    
    return memory     # Return the captured memory
            

poss2([1,1,1,6], 12)
# 2 --> (6,6)

poss2([2,3], 10)
# 4 --> (3,3,2,2)

poss2([2,7,5,1,6,32], 100)
# 5 --> (32, 32, 32, 2, 2)
```

Note also, this method is somewhat slow since it will iterate over every value in the for loop and do so in every recursion. A better approach to the same problem would be using something like

```
count = s // max(i)
s = s - count*max(i)
```

and then working your way down from the highest i in x.

Cheers!