# Get N-sized numbers that add up to a number X

Tags: javascript, recursion

My question maybe seems like duplicated but I can't find how to do this in vanilla javascript.
(I found answer in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074693/6337535).)

So basically I want to get a list of all possible combinations of number that sum up to a desired number.

For example:

```js
function sum_to_n(n,size){}

x = sum_to_n(6,3)
// [6,0,0] [5,1,0] [4,2,0] [4,1,1] [3,3,0] [3,2,1] [2,2,2]
```

This is what I can do so far:

```js
function sum_to_n(n, size, sum=[], limit) {
  if (size === 1) {
    sum.push(n)
    return sum
  }

  if (!limit) {
    limit = n
  }

  let start = Math.min(n, limit)
  let stop = Math.ceil(n/size) - 1

  for (let i = start; i > stop; i--) {
    let tmp = [...sum];
    tmp.push(i)
    let combination = sum_to_n(n-i, size - 1, tmp, i)
    if (combination) {
      console.log(combination) // this work
    }
  }
}

// I don't know how to make this work
let x = sum_to_n(6, 3)
// or maybe this
for (let y in sum_to_n(6,3)) {
  console.log(y)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closely related to [partitions of an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), which finds all distinct ways of breaking an integer into the sum of positive integers.  For instance, the partitions of `4` are `4`, `3 + 1`, `2 + 2`, `2 + 1 + 1`, and `1 + 1 + 1 + 1`.  Although there is probably a more direct way of calculating your sum, it's easy to do atop a `partitions` function:

```js
const partitions = (n, max = n) =>
  n == 0
    ? [[]]
  : n < 0
    ? []
  : Array .from ({length: Math .min (n, max)}, (_, i) => i + 1) // or use a `ramge` function
     .reverse()
     .flatMap (x => partitions (n - x, x) .map (p => [x, ...p]))

const sumToN = (n, c) => 
  partitions (n + c) 
    .filter (p => p .length == c)
    .map (p => p .map (x => x - 1))

console .log (sumToN (6, 3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(The `reverse` call is not strictly necessary, but the usual partition description is written in this order, as is your requested output.  The `Array.from (...)` call would be better expressed using a `range` function, but is not horrible inlined like this.)

We need to do two things: we have to find only those of the correct length, and we need to allow zeros as well as the positive numbers that `partition` generates.  We can do this by partitioning a larger number and subtracting `1` from each value in every partition, and filtering the results down to those with the proper length.

The larger number we need -- since we're going to subtract 1 for every one of our `c` elements in each partition -- is simply `n + c`.

This algorithm's performance is exponential in `n`.  But that's necessary as there are an exponential number of such partitions, and presumably an exponential number of results for your requested output. (I don't know a proof of this, and it's possible I'm wrong.  If I am, I'd love to see a sub-exponential algorithm.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';

function _sumToN(n, size, acc = [], solutions = []) {
  if (size === 0) {
    const sum = acc.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);

    return sum === n ? solutions.concat([acc]) : solutions;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    solutions = _sumToN(n, size - 1, acc.concat(i), solutions);

  return solutions;
}

function sumToN(n, size) {
  return _sumToN(n, size);
}

console.log(sumToN(6, 3));
```

The above uses a driver, `_sumToN`, which accepts an additional `acc` accumulator array, and a `solutions` array that will eventually hold all the solutions.  It iterates as follows:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
...
0 0 6
...
6 6 6
```

and saves off solutions when they sum to `n`.  There are of course optimizations that can be made, but hopefully this trivial implementation helps.

Comment: Thank you. It does really give me an idea. This solution will give duplicated number with different index eg. [1,2,3] [3,2,1]. But I guess just add some set checker and it’ll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let sum_to_n = (n, iteration_limit) => {
    let res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < iteration_limit; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < iteration_limit; j++) {
            for (let h = 0; h < iteration_limit; h++) {
                if(i+j+h == n){
                    res.push([i, j, h])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
};
```

This worked for me, however it does not have a size parameter.

Comment: The OP is looking for a recursive solution with dynamic size.  This is not recursive and the size is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
let getOperator = (size, arr, expect) => {
    let ev = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ev += `${arr[i]}+`;
    }
    return `${ev.slice(0, ev.length-1)} == ${expect}`;
}

let sum_to_n = (n, size, iteration_limit) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let identifiers = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
        let all_identifiers = [];
        let res = [];
        let ev = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            let r = identifiers[i];
            all_identifiers.push(r);
            ev += `for (let ${r} = 0; ${r} < iteration_limit; ${r}++){\n`;
        }
        let push_value_string = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < all_identifiers.length; i++) {
            push_value_string += `${all_identifiers[i]}, `;
        }
        ev += `\nif(${getOperator(size, all_identifiers, n)}){\nres.push([${push_value_string.slice(0, push_value_string.length-1)}]);\n}`;
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ev += "}";
            
        }
        console.log(ev);
        eval(ev);
        resolve(res);
    });
};


sum_to_n(15, 3, 100).then(console.log);
```

Basically depending on the size it will make a JavaScript code in a text `size` times, save what word it used for the for loop and check if the addition of all is equal to `n`. Then evaluate it and resolve it.

Comment: This seems like it misses the ball by a long shot.  `identifiers`... Promises for something that can clearly be synchronous... it's not recursive, which is what the OP wants...