# get all integer partition of a number

Tags: python, math

I basically have this question [Get all numbers that add up to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065553/get-all-numbers-that-add-up-to-a-number) but I also need 0 to be included.

I have tried the accepted answer and made it start from 0, basically like

```
def sum_to_n(n, size, limit=None):
    """Produce all lists of `size` positive integers in decreasing order
    that add up to `n`."""

    if size == 1:
        yield [n]
        return
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    start = 0
    stop = min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1
    for i in range(start, stop):
        for tail in sum_to_n(n - i, size - 1, i):
            yield [i] + tail
```

It worked out well for smaller numbers, but when I have larger numbers as targets it started to behave weird. For example:

```
for partition in sum_to_n(10,7):
    print(partition)
```

The output was like

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   10
1   0   0   0   0   0   9
1   1   0   0   0   0   8
1   1   1   0   0   0   7
1   1   1   1   0   0   6
1   1   1   1   1   0   5
1   1   1   1   1   1   4
2   0   0   0   0   0   8
2   1   0   0   0   0   7
2   1   1   0   0   0   6
2   1   1   1   0   0   5
2   1   1   1   1   0   4
2   1   1   1   1   1   3
2   2   0   0   0   0   6
2   2   1   0   0   0   5
2   2   1   1   0   0   4
2   2   1   1   1   0   3
2   2   1   1   1   1   2
2   2   2   0   0   0   4
2   2   2   1   0   0   3
2   2   2   1   1   0   2
2   2   2   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   0   0   7
3   1   0   0   0   0   6
3   1   1   0   0   0   5
3   1   1   1   0   0   4
3   1   1   1   1   0   3
3   1   1   1   1   1   2
3   2   0   0   0   0   5
3   2   1   0   0   0   4
3   2   1   1   0   0   3
3   2   1   1   1   0   2
3   2   1   1   1   1   1
4   0   0   0   0   0   6
4   1   0   0   0   0   5
4   1   1   0   0   0   4
4   1   1   1   0   0   3
4   1   1   1   1   0   2
4   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Here it clearly didn't include the case of 5 5 0 0 0 0 0. Also it has repeat cases like 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 and 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 which i don't want. What is wrong with this code? How could I modify it or any other thoughts on how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I see that some of these lists are repeated (although the numbers are in different order). Is that intended? Because the original answer is made so that this couldn't be a case.

Comment: Hm that's interesting, that was not my intention cuz i only need combinations for this step. I acc didn't find repeated cases, could you lmk which ones are repeated if you see any?

Comment: `0   4   1   1   1   1   1   1`, then a few more down below `0   1   1   1   1   1   1   4`

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing them out, I don't want repetitions as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you were going for:

```
def sum_to_n2(n, size, limit=None):
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    if size == 1:
        if n <= limit:
            yield[n]
    else:
        for i in range(0, limit+1):
            for tail in sum_to_n2(n - i, size - 1, min(i, n-i)):
                yield[i] + tail


print(list(sum_to_n2(10, 7)))
```

The differences with your code:

- checking if `limit is None` at the start, the function has a simpler `if .. else` (mostly cosmetic, easier to understand I feel and no need for the `return` to get out of there);
- you always yield `[n]` if `size == 1`, but that should only happen if `n <= limit`;
- you compute a limit on the range as `min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1`, but that's hard to track mentally (more so as range stops just short of it); I just say that the limit is the minimum of `i` (the number we're adding to the sequence, so no larger numbers allowed anymore) and `n-i` (the remainder, we don't need bigger numbers than that anymore), and pass that to the recursive call with `min(i, n-i)`.

I haven't done the full logic on where the computational error is in your code, but if I add the `n <= limit` condition to your code, it no longer includes zeroes. I'm sure you could figure it out when comparing values to my implementation of your algorithm, but I think mine is a bit cleaner anyway, so preferable.

Output for `6, 3` already shows a problem with your code, which is shorter than `10, 7`. Your output for `sum_to_n(5, 3)`:

```
[[0, 0, 5], [1, 0, 4], [1, 1, 3], [2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [3, 0, 2], [3, 1, 1]]
```

Note the duplicates in there `[2, 1, 2]` and `[2, 2, 1]` for example.

My output for `sum_to_n2(5, 3)`:

```
[[2, 2, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 0], [4, 1, 0], [5, 0, 0]]
```

Personally, but this is purely style, I prefer the output of this modified implementation:

```
def sum_to_n2(n, size, limit=None):
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    if size == 1:
        if n <= limit:
            yield[n]
    else:
        for i in range(limit, -1, -1):
            for tail in sum_to_n2(n - i, size - 1, min(i, n - i)):
                yield[i] + tail
```

Which results in (for `sum_to_n2(5, 3)`):

```
[[5, 0, 0], [4, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0], [3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1]]
```

It does this by inverting the range in the `for` loop.

By the way, here's a non-recursive one-liner that does it, but it's slow as mud :):

```
def sum_to_n_one_liner (n, sized):
    set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in filter(lambda s: sum(s) == n, product(*[range(n)]*size)))
```

It works by naively doing what needs to be done:

- take the numbers from 0 to `n`, `size` times
- compute the cartesian product, so you get all possible combinations of those numbers
- keep only the ones that sum up to `n`
- sort the resulting tuples and keep only unique ones

Comment: Note that this generates a list of lists, while the original linked question was asking for sets - however, OP was generating lists as well, and the quality of order not mattering was taking into account, so I chose lists as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get no repeated partitions, you can define the function so that it only generates results that are in non decreasing order.

```
def partition(N,size):
    if size == 1 :
        yield (N,)                           # base case, only 1 part
        return
    for a in range(N//size+1):               # smaller part followed by
        for p in partition(N-a*size,size-1): # equal or larger ones
            yield (a, *(n+a for n in p))     # recursing on delta only
```

Output:

```
for p in partition(10,7): print(p)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 8)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 7)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 6)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 6)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 5)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 5)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
(0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)
(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3)
(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
```